# How to run a flutter project in the emulator when there are more projects in a cloned repository

Tags: android-studio, github, flutter

I do  some flutter training online. And the code provided by the teacher is on the github. Unfortunately for me there are multiple projects in one repository and I don't know how to run  them in emulator.

What I did .
1). I forked the repo flutterCasts to my github account.
2). In Android Studio 3.5 I created new project  FlutterCasts and cloned it from my github repository.
3) Now I struggle to run the project 'news' or 'animation'   in the emulator.
[screenshot of the  project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaIrF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the lib folder you will seen all the dart code for each of the project. Look at the architecture of all files and know to it works.

Launch Android Studio>Tools>Android>AVD Manager and select Create Virtual Device.

Comment: I want to run the project in emulator